# Fastest way to resize image

Tags: python, performance, opencv

As in the title, which is the fastest way to resize an image? I'm using Python + OpenCV 2.11 (not openCV3), and it seems `cv2.resize()` is very slow.

We can use CUDA with OpenCV3 (http://www.coldvision.io/2015/12/22/image-resize-with-opencv-and-cuda/), but is it supported in OpenCV 2?

Comment: Even if you do not upgrade to OpenCV3, why don't you use the most actual version of OpenCV2 (2.4.12?)? Can you give sample code and a benchmark?

Comment: OpenCV 3 has `cudawarping` class, I can't find it in OpenCV2. The sample code is in the link.

Comment: You are not saying what you are resizing from and to which can make a difference. " it seems cv2.resize() is very slow" well is it? If you want to be certain try writing some speed tests to confirm. You should write some tests with different programs with the same images.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV 2 has gpu module but unfortunately there's no bindings for Python.

Answer (score 4):

CUDA programming comes with a pretty big warmup- and code complexity overhead itself.

There exists a [SIMD fork of Pillow](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd), which claims to have much better performance than ImageMagick or plain Pillow, but there are no comparisons to OpenCV. Maybe worth checking out how they compare.

Comment: Resulting image quality is far superior for pillow compared to opencv